# Multivariate series expansion in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Does anyone know if there is a built-in function in sympy to obtain a multivariate series expansion of the form

```
f(x,y) = a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*x*y + f*y**2 + ...
```

i.e. by ascending order in all variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you start with (a polynomial, some other (analytic) function)?
What kind of output do you expect? (A polynomial, a list of monomials, something different?)

Comment: Hi Piotr, I am interested in power series expansions of any multivariate function, as a multivariate variant of "series":

Comment: I had meant to continue with an example: something like (exp(x)*exp(y)).series() giving 1 + x + y + x**2/2 + x*y + y**2/2 + ...

Answer (score 6):

It is maybe too late but here is what I would do.
It is not exactly a builtin function but it does the job.
The idea is to introduce a temporary variable (eps) using substitutions and to expand the series over it.
Here is an example:

```
import sympy
x, y , eps = sympy.symbols('x y eps')
f = sympy.exp(x-y)
f.subs(x,x*eps).subs(y,y*eps).series(eps).removeO().subs(eps,1)
```

Note that using this technique you can have "asymmetric" expansions in x and y.
For instance:
`f.subs(x,x*eps).subs(y,y*eps**2)` ...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that currently (sympy build 0.7.5), there is no built-in function in sympy that will handle multivariate series expansions.

There appears to be support for series expansion of multivariate functions **in *one* variable only**. You can see this in the docstring of `_eval_nseries` in the `function` documentation [here](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.4/_modules/sympy/core/function.html).  If this is important to you, you can comment on the [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) or join the [mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sympy).

So, to be clear, this works:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sp
In [2]: x, y = sp.symbols('x,y')
In [3]: g = sp.exp(-x*y)
In [4]: g
Out[4]: exp(-x*y)
In [5]: g.series(x, 0)
Out[5]: 1 - x*y + x**2*y**2/2 - x**3*y**3/6 + x**4*y**4/24 - x**5*y**5/120 + O(x**6)
In [6]: g.series(y, 0)
Out[6]: 1 - x*y + x**2*y**2/2 - x**3*y**3/6 + x**4*y**4/24 - x**5*y**5/120 + O(y**6)
```

but there is none of your desired functionality in any of the following:

```
In [7]: g.series((x, y), (0, 0))
Out[7]: exp(-x*y)

In [8]: g.series((x, 0), (y, 0))
Out[8]: exp(-x*y)

In [9]: g.series(x, 0, y, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-20c1ab732928> in <module>()
----> 1 g.series(x, 0, y, 0)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.pyc in series(self, x, x0, n, dir, logx)
   2401                 return self
   2402 
-> 2403         if len(dir) != 1 or dir not in '+-':
   2404             raise ValueError("Dir must be '+' or '-'")
   2405 

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

In [10]: g.series(x, y, 0, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-32b57736cd3d> in <module>()
----> 1 g.series(x, y, 0, 0)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.pyc in series(self, x, x0, n, dir, logx)
   2401                 return self
   2402 
-> 2403         if len(dir) != 1 or dir not in '+-':
   2404             raise ValueError("Dir must be '+' or '-'")
   2405 

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```